# How to get only "intent" field from LUIS returned JSON result using C#

Tags: c#, json, azure-language-understanding

how do I get only the "intent" field from the JSON format code from LUIS return result in C#? 
I have already done deserialization like this:

```
public class ResponseContent
{
    [BsonId]
    public string query { get; set; }
    public string topScoringIntent { get; set; }
    public string intent { get; set; }
    public string entities { get; set; }
}

public class topScoringIntent
{
    public string intent { get; set; }
    public string score { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the LUIS return result:

```
"query": "Hello.",
"topScoringIntent": 
{
"intent": "Greeting",
"score": 0.9447609
},
"intents": 
[
{
  "intent": "Greeting",
  "score": 0.9447609
},
{
  "intent": "Request",
  "score": 0.09726282
},
{
  "intent": "None",
  "score": 5.523394E-10
}
],
"entities": []
```

And I only want the "intent" field from the "TopScoringIntent". How can I get that using C#? Below is the code that I tried but nothing came out:

```
var uri = "https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/" + luisAppId + "?" + queryString;
var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var responseitem = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseContent,Formatting.Indented);
JToken content = JToken.Parse(responseitem);
var intentOnly = (from s in content.Children()["ResponseContent"]select s).ToList();
foreach (var item in intentOnly.Children().ToList())
{
  Console.WriteLine(item.ToObject<ResponseContent>().TopScoringIntent);
}
```

This is not a bot so I am not using any bot framework to do this. 
Thank you.

Comment: Debug it, and see the format of the "content" object, there you will notice how to query it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get it done by using the following code:

```
var jsonresponse = JObject.Parse(responseContent);
intentonly = jsonresponse.SelectToken("intents[0].intent").ToString();
```